# Instructions on how to setup remote kernel on Win 10

Tags: windows, remote-access

I'd like to use my home PC to help make calculations when I use my laptop at work.
Both are Win 10 machines (Mathematica version: home - v11 / work - v10). I couldn't find a tutorial on how to setup a local kernel at home. All I can find is a tutorial on [how to connect to a remote kernel](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ConnectToARemoteKernel.html), but not how to create one.

Comment: This is likely not going to be easy.  First, you need to find a way to start a program remotely on that computer (this is a task unrelated to Mathematica). On Unix-like operating systems one can usually use SSH. I do not know what to use on Windows.  Once this is done, you will need to make sure that network communication between your home computer and laptop is unrestricted. With a home internet connection, this is not usually easy, as the typical setup does not allow accessing the computer from the outside through the internet.

Comment: Only when all this is done do we need to start thinking about how to set up Mathematica. Since the above problems are not related to Mathematica, you can consider asking about them on other sites (where it may be easier to find an answer).  Personally I can't give you an answer for Windows.

Comment: That's what I thought. It would take too much work to setup everything, port forwarding, ssh and what not. Thanks

Comment: If you get it working, please report back. I am sure many people want to do this.